# servlet code structure / pattern ideas ? writing response

Tags: java, design-patterns, servlets

I have a simple servlet at the moment. I need it to call a static jar method and return its response.

1) Can someone recommend a suitable structure ie do I need to create factories and handler classes etc...

2) How should I encode the hash in the response ... Is the simply writing to output stream ok do something else ? Ie write to headers etc.. Another App will be reading the response.

3) Not sure about handling nulls etc..

```
package myproj.servlet;

//Std imports
//Serlet imports
import myproj.hash.HashGenerator;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{

String hashcode;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String accountName = req.getParameter("accountName");

    try {
        hashcode = HashGenerator.hash(accountName);
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter(); 
        //[EDIT] was returning accountName by accident
        out.print(hashcode );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Some logging code
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help (command pattern) http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip68.html

Comment: Do you really need a raw Servlet or have you considered a higher level framework like Spring MVC, JSF, Wicket, etc.?

Comment: @artbristol: given how trivially simple the app is, a full-blown framework seems like overkill.

Comment: True, but depends on the framework. Spring MVC is pretty easy to set up. Most frameworks come with a sample/tutorial app you can just steal, plus you're going to at least have to deal with the concurrency issues mentioned in Adeel's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, your `hashcode` is not thread-safe.

1. After looking to your provided snippet. I don't think so. It is fairly simple thing.
2. You are getting `accountName` as parameter, and then writing the same back. Is that you want? Or you mean respond the hashed version.
3. You might like to validate `accountName` parameter, since it is the input provided by user.

Comment: opps yes your right .. my sanitizing of this code for the web introduced that :) ill be returning the hashcode

Comment: So I should move it within doPost and synchronize the method ?

Comment: @wmitchell: You need not synchronize the method, as everything is gonna be local, so will be on stack.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Servlets directly, it helps to create a `BaseServlet` class to inherit from, which provides convenience methods for:

- parameter handling / validation
- parsing path information
- mapping Java exceptions to HTTP result codes
- etc...

Usually you want to define a single `handle(HttpRequest req, HttpResponse)` method, called from doGet/doPost, so you can move all the generic error handling outside your implementing class. Depending on how complex your responses are, you may even want to do `handle(PrintWriter out)` so you don't have to fuss with the io stuff every time.

Having factories for the sake of having factories is a very Java thing to do, but I don't see how that would benefit you here.

2) depends entirely on what the contract between your apps is, and how complex you expect their interaction to become in the future.

3) you definitely want to validate your parameters and send back a `400` status code if you don't have valid input.

Adeel already pointed out the glaring issue with `hashcode`.

If you expect this to become more complex, [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is an excellent framework for implementing app-to-app remote services (even if they aren't, strictly speaking, RESTful).